# Video streaming using ASP.NET CORE and SignalR

Tags: asp.net-core, signalr, video-streaming, webrtc

The task is to be able to connect to cameras from car DVRs and to save video from cameras to a database or file system in real time (i.e. somehow stream should be saved, but not the whole video object at once). Now I am making a prototype and trying to make sure that the video from my webcam is broadcast in a browser and saved in parallel to a database or file system. I googled for several days on how to do this and how it will be better and a little confused (between WebRtc and SignalR, since the first one is hard to understand and the second is not fully described on the internet examples which I found). I will be very glad if someone tell me with the help of which technologies and how exactly this can be done (examples are welcome, since the task needs to be done quickly). Now I look towards ASP.NET CORE and SignalR (asynchronous streams). but I don’t really understand, is it possible to solve my problem with the help of these technologies? if not, what technologies should I try? if so, how to implement the solution using these technologies?

UPD: I need to implement something like Azure Media Services (https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/media-services/)

Comment: Neither one seems to be really suitable for it. SignalR is for messages/data, not video streaming and WebRtc is for peer-to-peer (user to user, no server involved). ASP.NET Core per see is for web applications, not for streaming either. Neither is HTTP well suited for that which is what ASP.NET Core uses essentially). You 'd need something on a lower level, operating on TCP or UDP level

Comment: Thanks for a quick response @Tseng! But I can not agree with you... It seems that there are some solutions for this really exist, but I do not know how to fully implement this. As for the SignalR, see David Pine's video: https://youtu.be/i3RXbOY6-0I?t=2586 and demo source repositoryhttps://github.com/IEvangelist/IEvangelist.SignalR.Streaming (it seems like we can do this, but not clear how to save the real time stream).

Comment: @Tseng, as for the WebRtc, we can use RTCPeerConnection with the server (see Adam Roach's comment https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mozilla.dev.media/pos7woJMimo and WebRtc examples https://webrtc.github.io/samples/), and WebSockets somehow. Also, as I know, SignalR is based on the WebSockets and ASP.NET Core can be just WebSocket server, something like this...

Comment: None of it really related. The first video is sending processed image (processed on the server and turned into ascii) data as ascii to the web application via messages. Thats not really video streaming per se. And the second like doesnt say anything that you do it via http and mentions different protocols such as SRTP. For streaming you need a different protocol, but ASP.NET Core operates on HTTP protocol, you need something thats lower level than that and directly operates on TCP or UDP and a library that can understand / communicate with protocols used for streaming video or audio data